# How can I revise my code to improve my processing speed

Tags: r

I have to run a similar code across columns in a large matrix.

```
set.seed(1)

my_vector <- runif( 10000 )

my_sums <- NULL

for ( l in 1:length( my_vector ) ) {

  current_result <- my_vector[ my_vector < runif( 1 ) ]

  my_sums[l] <- sum( current_result )

}

head(my_sums)
# [1]   21.45613 2248.31463 2650.46104   62.82708   11.11391   86.21950
```

`Sys.time` results:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   1.14    0.00    1.14
```

Any ideas on how to improve performance?

Comment: I got a small boost in time with `replicate(1e4, sum(my_vector[my_vector < runif(1)]))`

Comment: I also got an improvement on your loop by allocating the right size for `my_sums` ahead of time. `my_sums <- numeric(10000)`

Comment: It's always a bad idea to grow objects in a loop. Avoid this when you can, and here, as Pierre shows, it is possible to do.

Comment: I actually got a 1/10 second longer on my machine when doing `my_sums <- numeric(10000)` instead of how OP does it.

Comment: @AntonioDamico: Please don't randomly add `rcpp` tags.  Removing it now.

Comment: curious if there's a smart `rcpp` or other high performance computing solution here.  can't figure out a good way to do this in base r

Comment: How large is your actual problem? Is `n=10000` accurate?

Comment: If you want to run a similar code across columns in a large `matrix`, it would be better to present a reproducible example that matches this data structure , e.g. a `matrix`, `data.frame`, `data.table`

Answer (score 19):

[Matt Dowle's excellent data.table approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37696589/3573401) in base `R`

```
system.time({
  set.seed(1)
  my_vector <- runif(10000)
  x <- runif(10000)
  sorted <- sort(my_vector)
  ind <- findInterval(x, sorted) + 1
  my_sums <- c(0, cumsum(sorted))[ind]
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 

head(my_sums)
#[1]   21.45613 2248.31463 2650.46104   62.82708   11.11391   86.21950
```

Comment: +1 for super fast. However, there is an error you should correct.  Values of `x` less than `min(my_vector)` will return an index of 0.  Subsetting `cumsum(sorted)[ind=0]` will produce `NULL` for such values, thereby erasing these from the `my_sums` vector, which will therefore be shorter than `my_vector`.  The solution is to use `my_sums <- c(0,cumsum(sorted))[ind+1]`

Comment: @dww  Corrected as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you edit the `0` to `-Inf`?  It was right with @dww's solution in comment above returning `0` when `x<min(my_vector)`.  But now it'll return `-Inf` for those.

Comment: @MattDowle, I had `findInterval(x, c(-Inf, sorted))` in the back of my mind. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 15):

```
require(data.table)

system.time({
  set.seed(1)
  my_vector = runif(10000)
  DT = data.table(my_vector)
  setkey(DT, my_vector)
  DT[,cumsum:=cumsum(my_vector)]
  my_sums = DT[.(runif(10000)), cumsum, roll=TRUE]
  my_sums[is.na(my_sums)] = 0
})

head(my_sums)
# [1]   21.45613 2248.31463 2650.46104   62.82708   11.11391   86.21950

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.004   0.000   0.004
```

Comment: Nice answer +1. One small issue where behaviour of this differs from code in OP: `DT[.(x), cumsum, roll=TRUE]` returns `NA` for `x < min (my_vector)`. whereas `sum()` in OP gives 0 in such cases.

Comment: @dww Well spotted. Fixed by edit to include a 0 at the start of `my_vector`. No change to timing.

Comment: @dww Alternatively, adding a last line `my_sums[is.na(my_sums)] = 0` avoids adding the first 0. Also doesn't change timing.

Comment: @dww So I changed it to the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

What about `sapply`?

```
temp <- sapply(seq_along(my_vector), function(l){

  current_result <- my_vector[ my_vector < runif( 1 ) ]
  my_sums[l] <- sum( current_result )

})
```

Gives this some performance improvements?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: the addition of `sort()` cuts my time down to 0.74. The time it takes to sort `my_vector` is trivial on this example, but may be costly on larger/ different data.

```
set.seed(1)

my_vector <- runif( 10000 )
n<-runif(10000)
my_sums <- 1:10000
system.time(my_vector<-sort(my_vector))

#user  system elapsed 
# 0       0       0 
# my_vector is now sorted.


system.time(
for ( l in 1:length( my_vector ) ) {

my_sums[l] <- sum(my_vector[my_vector < n[l]])
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.73    0.00    0.74 

head(my_sums)
# [1]   21.4561 2248.3146 2650.4610   62.8271   11.1139   86.2195
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to apply the same function across columns in a large matrix, I would suggest this:

```
dt <- data.table( my_vector1 = runif( 1000000 ),
                  my_vector2 = runif( 1000000 ),
                  my_vector3 = runif( 1000000 ))

cols <- paste0(names(dt),"_csum")

setkey(dt)

dt[, (cols) := lapply (.SD, function(x)  cumsum(x) )]


> head(dt)
#>      my_vector1 my_vector2 my_vector3 my_vector1_csum my_vector2_csum my_vector3_csum
#> 1: 7.664785e-07 0.47817820  0.9008552    7.664785e-07       0.4781782       0.9008552
#> 2: 8.875504e-07 0.24142375  0.9849384    1.654029e-06       0.7196019       1.8857936
#> 3: 1.326203e-06 0.48592786  0.3791094    2.980232e-06       1.2055298       2.2649030
#> 4: 2.730172e-06 0.76847160  0.5732031    5.710404e-06       1.9740014       2.8381061
#> 5: 4.655216e-06 0.01094117  0.5120915    1.036562e-05       1.9849426       3.3501976
```

Additionally, the [library `profvis`](https://github.com/rstudio/profvis) is really helpful in identifying the time and memory consumption of each line in your code. [Example here](http://rpubs.com/wch/178493).