# Fast sum of values of a vector above given thresholds

Tags: r, performance, loops, vector

I have a vector of threshold values, `thresholds`, and another vector, `x`. I'd like to create a new vector, say `vec_sum`, of the same length as `thresholds`, that stores, for each element of `thresholds`, the sum of values of `x` larger than this element.

What is the fastest way of doing this? 
The naive way I'm doing it is

```
vec_sum <- rep(NA,length(thresholds))
for(i in seq_along(thresholds))
{
   vec_sum[i] <- sum(x[x>thresholds[i]])
}
```

In case it helps, thresholds is already sorted.

Comment: Not any different from your attempt but I would have used `sapply` instead of `for` loop `sapply(thresholds, function(i) sum(x[x>i]))`

Comment: `sorted <- sort(x); sum(x) - cumsum(sorted)[findInterval(thresholds, sorted)]` (ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617125/how-can-i-revise-my-code-to-improve-my-processing-speed/37697979#37697979)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution using `cumsum`:

```
f1 <- function(v, th){
    v2 <- v[order(v)]
    v2s <- rev(cumsum(rev(v2)))
    return(v2s[findInterval(th, v2) + 1])
}
```

Here are some tests and comparison with the other answer (as well as the example data) by Ronak:

```
f2 <- function(x, thresholds){
    if (all(x < thresholds[1])) return(rep(0, length(thresholds)))
    if (all(x > thresholds[length(thresholds)])) return(rep(sum(x), length(thresholds)))
    return(rev(cumsum(rev(tapply(x, 
        findInterval(x, thresholds, left.open = TRUE), sum)[-1]))))
}

test_th <- c(3, 5, 10)
test_x <- c(2, 3, 1, 19, 4, 6, 5, 15, 7:14, 16:18, 20)

vec_sum <- rep(NA,length(test_th))
for(i in seq_along(test_th)) {
    vec_sum[i] <- sum(test_x[test_x>test_th[i]])
}

all(dplyr::near(f1(test_x, test_th), vec_sum))
# [1] TRUE
all(dplyr::near(f2(test_x, test_th), vec_sum))
# [1] TRUE


set.seed(123)
test_x <- rnorm(10000)
test_th <- sort(rnorm(100)) ## f2 requires sorted threshold values

vec_sum <- rep(NA,length(test_th))
for(i in seq_along(test_th)) {
    vec_sum[i] <- sum(test_x[test_x>test_th[i]])
}
all(dplyr::near(f1(test_x, test_th), vec_sum))
# [1] TRUE
all(dplyr::near(f2(test_x, test_th), vec_sum))
# [1] FALSE
# Warning message:
# In x - y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    a = f1(test_x, test_th),
    b = f2(test_x, test_th)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
#     a  587.116  682.864  900.3572  694.713  703.726 10647.206   100
#     b 1157.213 1203.063 1260.0663 1223.600 1258.552  2143.069   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any faster, but we can use `findInterval` to cut `x` by `thresholds`. We take `sum` of each group using `tapply` and take `cumsum` in reverse.

```
as.integer(rev(cumsum(rev(tapply(x, 
          findInterval(x, thresholds, left.open = TRUE), sum)[-1]))))
```

Tested on

```
thresholds <- c(3, 5, 10)
x <- c(2, 3, 1, 19, 4, 6, 5, 15, 7:14, 16:18, 20) #1:20 in random order
vec_sum <- rep(NA,length(thresholds))

for(i in seq_along(thresholds)) {
  vec_sum[i] <- sum(x[x>thresholds[i]])
}
vec_sum
#[1] 204 195 155
```

Using the proposed solution

```
as.integer(rev(cumsum(rev(tapply(x, 
          findInterval(x, thresholds, left.open = TRUE), sum)[-1]))))
#[1] 204 195 155
```

---

Explaining the answer. `findInterval` returns groups where each value of `x` belongs

```
findInterval(x, thresholds, left.open = TRUE)
#[1] 0 0 0 3 1 2 1 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

We use `tapply` to get `sum` of each group

```
tapply(x, findInterval(x, thresholds, left.open = TRUE), sum)
#  0   1   2   3 
#  6   9  40 155
```

0-group should be excluded since they are smaller than all the values of `threshold` (hence `-1`). Group 2 should also contain sum from group 1 and group 3 should contain sum of group 1 and 2. So we `rev`erse the sequence and take `cumsum`

```
cumsum(rev(tapply(x, findInterval(x, thresholds, left.open = TRUE), sum)[-1]))

#  3   2   1 
#155 195 204
```

To get it in original order and to match it with `threshold` we `rev`erse it again

```
rev(cumsum(rev(tapply(x, findInterval(x, thresholds, left.open = TRUE), sum)[-1])))
#  1   2   3 
#204 195 155
```

---

**Edge Cases :**

If there are all values below threshold or all values above threshold, we might need to do an extra check and return the following.

```
if (all(x < thresholds[1]))   rep(0, length(thresholds))
if (all(x > thresholds[length(thresholds)])) rep(sum(x), length(thresholds))
```

Comment: I see, your methods don't work when all x is smaller than thresholds.

Comment: @cuttlefish44 yes, and also when all x is greater than thresholds. I updated the answer to handle those cases.

Comment: It seems that your method doesn't work properly when the vector is not of integers. I used a slightly revised version of your method to test (see `f2` in my post) and I might have misunderstood your method.